# sudo unable to write to /var/lib/sudo/malik/tty1

Tags: 14.04, sudo, vmware

I am using Ubuntu 14. I mistakenly used this command

```
sudo fsck -Af -M
```

which started to giving me this whenever I do anything:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Please don't add code or output as image, rather copy-paste the content into your question and format it as code ( `{ }` )

Comment: actually it was hard for me to write whole bcz i am on Alt+ctrl+F1 screen

Answer (score 0):

You have to run

```
sudo chown -R malik:malik sudo
```

from within the path `/var/lib`
Or better run it providing the full path

```
sudo chown -R malik:malik /var/lib/sudo
```

from anywhere on the system.

---

The `/` before `sudo` in your command makes it looking for the file/folder `sudo` in the root directory `/` which doesn't exist in your case and is not what you want.

---

Anyway probably not the best thing to do so in general.

---

From the comments here I understand that your original problem is not having permissions to run

```
cd /home/malik
```

Than you probably don't have to change anything in `/var/lib` but rather Run the comment on the home folder instead

```
sudo chown -R malik:malik /home/malik
```

In order to set the ownership of the home folder and all content to user `malik` and the group to `malik`.

Additionally you might also need to run (without `-R`)

```
sudo chmod '0770' /home/malik
```

in order to make the folder read-, write- and accessable for the user `malik` and members of the group `malik` and disable read, write and access for other users.

Comment: derHugo's answer is correct, but I doubt that it is a good idea to change ownership of /var/lib/sudo.

Comment: ownership? like chmod 755 something?

Comment: still giving same error sudo unable to write to /var/lib/sudo/malik/tty1 No such directory or file

Comment: even i tried from root like sudo -s and written same sudo chown -R malik:malik /var/lib/sudo and then after exiting i tried to access my directory cd home/malik gives me -bash: cd: malik : Permission denied

Comment: any idea???????

Comment: You write in your comment that you did `cd home/malik`. What was your current directory when you issued this command? If it was `/` then what gives `ls -ld /home/malik`?

Comment: @user3162878 Then probably you should try to change ownership (`chown`) and/or permissions (`chmod`) of this `/home/malik` folder not something in `/var/lib`. What is the original goal of your attempts? Does the file `/var/lib/sudo/malik/tty1` exist at all?